# Find a point in 3d collinear with 2 other points

Tags: python, algorithm, 3d, point

I need to write a script in python which given coordinates of 2 points in 3d space finds a collinear point in distane 1 unit from one the given points. This third point must lay between those two given.
I think I will manage with scripting but I am not really sure how to calculate it from mathematical point of view. I found some stuff on google, but they do not answer my question.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What do you mean by "in distance 1 unit from one of the points"?

Comment: It's worth observing that there may be no valid solution when the two points are too close together.

Answer (score 2):

Given 2 points, (x1,y1,z1) and (x2,y2,z2), you can take the difference between the two, so you end up with (x2-x1,y2-y1,z2-z1).  Take the norm of this (i.e. take the distance between the original 2 points), and divide (x2-x1,y2-y1,z2-z1) by that value. You now have a vector with the same slope as the line between the first 2 points, but it has magnitude one, since you normalized it (by dividing by its magnitude).  Then add/subtract that vector to one of the original points to get your final answer.